# Integration with Salesforce Wave

Tags: integration, einstein-analytics

I was wondering if anyone has done an integration with Salesforce Wave? We are getting an error for an "Overwrite" operation.

> Error: Failed to generate Salesforce Analytics binary dataset.
>
> SF Analytics Dataset Upload Error: file insert failed, Salesforce
>   error:
>
> Field Integrity Exception Has Occurred.

A field integrity exception often indicates that a field property has been changed between append or upsert operations.
 This can also occur if changes have been made to FiscalMonthOffset or IsYearEndFiscal.
 Field integrity can be fixed by restoring all fields and properties to their original values or by using an Overwrite operation.

Field integrity can also indicate a unique key violation.

Details:

> statusCode={FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION} message={Exceeded the maximum
>   number of daily uploads.} The operation "" failed.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_limits.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Comment: In case it helps someone...

Comment: I'm uploading dozens of records per hour and I'm getting this error. I was uploading files with errors to test the logging/reporting process. Could that be leading to this error? Does Wave stop you from uploading if you have too many errors?